# ARKit: Change FOV for rendered content

Tags: arkit

I'm looking to change the field of view for the rendered content in my AR session. Obviously we can't change the raw camera FOV, but I think it should be possible to change the field of view for the rendered SceneKit content.

Changing the camera field of view is trivial in a raw SceneKit SCNCamera... but I don't know how to do this within an ARSCNView.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to access the `pointOfView` property of your `ARSCNView` (and then retrieve the active `SCNCamera`).

If that doesn't work (ARKit changing the camera property every frame etc.), you can always go the path of writing the code yourself by using `ARSession` directly with `SCNView`.

Note that unless you have a 3D scene covering the entire camera stream, changing the FoV of your virtual camera would break the AR registration (alignment).

Answer (score 0):

The [developer documentation for ARSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsession) suggests "If you build your own renderer for AR content, you'll need to instantiate and maintain an ARSession object yourself."

This repo does this: https://github.com/hanleyweng/iOS-ARKit-Headset-View

Answer (score 0):

This code will retrieve the camera from an `ARSCNView` if there is one:

`sceneView.scene.rootNode.childNodes.first(where: { $0.camera != nil})`

Note that this will return the camera's associated node, which you may need if you want to control its position or angle directly. The `SCNCamera` itself is stored in the node's `camera` property.

It's best not to touch the AR camera if you can avoid it as it will mess up the association between the world model and the scene. I occasionally use this technique if I want a control system that can optionally use AR to track device motion and angle, but which doesn't have to translate into real-world coordinates (i.e. VR apps that don't display the camera feed).

Essentially, I'd only do this if you're using `AROrientationTrackingConfiguration` or similar.

*EDIT* I should probably mention that ARKit overrides the camera's `projectionTransform` property, so you probably won't be able to set `fieldOfView` manually. I've had some success setting `xFov` and `yFov`, but since these are deprecated you shouldn't rely on them.